# How to use TWO SpringResourceTemplateResolver Beans?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Since Thymeleaf 3, Thymeleaf prefers the use of `SpringResourceTemplateResolver` (https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf3migration.html). So I decided to go from `ClassLoaderTemplateResolver` to `SpringResourceTemplateResolver`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
        registry.setOrder(1);
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        resolver.setOrder(0);
        resolver.setCheckExistence(true);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver2() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/templates-2/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        resolver.setCheckExistence(true);
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when implementig like this, I'll get an error:
`Error resolving template [index], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers`.

To be honest, I've simple replaced `ClassLoaderTemplateResolver` with `SpringResourceTemplateResolver` in the hope, this will work. It doesn't. But searching for a working solution dealing with two template locations, all I find are outdated samples using ClassLoaderTemplateResolvers.

Trying to implement the code snippet provided by Thymeleaf as shown here https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf3migration.html won't work either when using two template directories, besides the fact, that this code itself uses the deprecated WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.

Is there any example how to configure a Spring Boot application using Thymeleaf having two or more template locations which isn't completely outdated?

Comment: The order starts by default with the value : 1
Or you are using 0, that's why it is not detected.
@see thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE-javadoc.jar look at /org/thymeleaf/templateresolver/AbstractTemplateResolver.html#setOrder(java.lang.Integer)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Spring Boot, you can add an extra resolver on top of the default one like this:

First, add this to `application.properties`:

```
# This ensures that the default HTML template resolver of Thymeleaf has priority over our custom SVG resolver
spring.thymeleaf.template-resolver-order=0
```

Then add the extra resolver in a `@Configuration` class:

```
@Configuration
public class MyApplicationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ITemplateResolver svgTemplateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/svg/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".svg");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("XML");

        return resolver;
    }
}
```

There is no need to manually define `SpringTemplateEngine` and `ViewResolver` beans.

You can disable caching during development using `spring.thymeleaf.cache=false`.

Answer (score 2):

So after a while and many many tryouts I've finally got the templates working. Since there isn't any decent answer to my question flying round the internet, I will post my solution for others:

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(@Autowired ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(this.applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates-1/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        templateResolver.setOrder(1);
        templateResolver.setCheckExistence(true); /* FYI: necessary to chain TemplateResolvers */
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);     /* FYI: during development -> false, so that we can see changes we make */
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver2() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(this.applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates-2/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        templateResolver.setOrder(2);
        templateResolver.setCheckExistence(true); /* FYI: necessary to chain TemplateResolvers */
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);     /* FYI: during development -> false, so that we can see changes we make */
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        /* SpringTemplateEngine automatically applies SpringStandardDialect and
           enables Spring's own MessageSource message resolution mechanisms. */
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();

        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(this.templateResolver());
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(this.templateResolver2());

        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(this.templateEngine());
        viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        viewResolver.setCache(false);   /* FYI: during development -> false */
        viewResolver.setOrder(1);
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

I hope this will help others to save time and nerves^^.